# Best way to insert a possibly existing row in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm writing an export script that will insert rows from one database to another. This query may be executed numerous times, and new data may or may not be present.

I have read up on a few different ways of inserting when there are possible values:
ON DUPLICATE IGNORE, INSERT IGNORE, REPLACE, etc

Currently I have chosen REPLACE but I am not sure if it is the best choice. The row I am inserting has a field called DateCreated. If the entry already exists, I don't want to update it, just skip it.

What MySQL query do I need to run to SKIP on DUPLICATE? DUPLICATE IGNORE?

Is using DUPLICATE IGNORE the same as UPDATE IGNORE as in it ignores all insert errors, like wrong number of fields, etc?

Answer (score 3):

You should add UNIQUE KEY on DateCreated and use INSERT IGNORE.

REPLACE will remove your old data and insert new one. If you want to update some data in existing row you should use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. It will be faster than REPLACE.

Comment: Several entries can all be added on the same date. If I set UNIQUE KEY, would that make it so I can only add one entry a day?

Comment: @Aaa Yes. The first date will be inserted only.

Answer (score 0):

I would use INSERT IGNORE because REPLACE first deletes the record and then inserts a new one. IGNORE won't ignore wrong number of columns error.

Use ON DUPLICATE only when there is any column to update in case of duplicate record. Like, a counter column for example.

Comment: So for this method, I should just make extra sure there won't be any other errors, because they would generate warnings instead of errors and still perform the insert, correct? Would INSERT IGNORE insert the new data, and "ignore" that there is already existing data, or would INSERT IGNORE "skip" the row all together?

Comment: INSERT IGNORE skips the row, so you will have your old row intact. Notice that duplicate rows are determined using the PRIMARY and UNIKE KEYS.